# How can 17 y.o. high school students intuit that P(n, r) stops at $n - (r - 1)$, not $n - r$?

Tags: combinatorics

Every year, some 17 y.o. student makes the mistake of stopping $P(n, r)$ at $\color{darkorange}{(n - r)}$, rather than $\color{forestgreen}{(n - (r - 1))}$. Because they are in their last year of high school, they do understand why. But they goof up because this is counterintuitive, because $P(n, r)$ contains $r$, but the last term contains $\color{forestgreen}{r - 1}$.

As lined in red below, I want students to understand this, not just memorize. How can they intuit this?

> [image]

David Patrick, [BS Math & Computer Science, MS Math (Carnegie Mellon),  PhD Math (MIT)](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/David_Patrick). *Introduction to Counting & Probability* (2005), p 20.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$P(n,r)$ computes the number of permutations of $r$ objects (out of a choice of $n$). So in the end there should only be $r$ terms in the product. Since the 1st term is $n$ and the 2nd term is $n-1$, then the $r$th term is $n-(r-1)$.

What they are making is an [off-by-one error](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error). In a discrete topics course, they need to learn about this common mistake.

Update: Another way to explain it is to ask how many items are you NOT using. The answer is $n-r$. So then $n-r$ should NOT be a term in the product. So in your example of 3 officers out of 30. There are $30-3=27$ UNused people. So the product counts down from 30 but does NOT use 27 (so stops at 28).

Answer (score 6):

The way I think about it, and also the way I thought about it in high school, is "it's a product of $r$ consecutive numbers, sort of like $r \times (r-1) \times \cdots \times 2 \times 1$. So the difference between the first factor and the last factor is $r-1$."

This is an issue that shows up in lots of places: In a list of $r$ consecutive integers, the difference between the first one and the last one is $r-1$. It even has a name: [Fence post error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error#Fencepost_error). So just learn that this is a standard place one can go wrong and get in the habit of subtracting the last term from the first term and comparing with the difference between $r$ and $1$ when you do computations like this.

Comment: Beat me by 36 seconds! (And it couldn't figure out how to create the link on my Android device.)

Answer (score 5):

This is somewhere between an answer and a comment. I think the other answers mentioning the fence post error get to the heart of it. In other words, is this really about permutations specifically? Because if their intuition says that $n-r$ should appear in the formula, they're correct; $P(n,r)=n!/(n-r)!$

Their real problem doesn't seem to be faulty intuition (because who really has an intuitive feel for, say, the number of permutations of 36 objects out of 177?). It seems to me that they're just vaguely remembering a formula or a process that they don't have a complete understanding of and plugging in the wrong numbers, ie they're *hoping* or *guessing* that the answer takes a certain form, not intuiting. The fact that they do understand why they can stop at $n-r+1$ when it's explained to them is a good sign.

Comment: It's definitely an off-by-one error, but it seems to me that it's more a start-your-counting-with-zero-rather-than-one error than a fencepost error. Maybe I'm just not seeing how the fencepost analogy applies...

Comment: @WillOrrick  Imagine a fence with $r$ posts sitting on the number line. If the rightmost post is on $n$, then the left most post is on $n-r+1$.  It seems like a good analogy to me, but what do I know?

Comment: @WillOrrick I was using fencepost and off-by-one interchangeably, but David explained it well; in the example problem from the textbook, the first post is 30, the second 29, and the the third is 28.

Comment: @DavidESpeyer, Thierry I’ve always seen the fence post analogy as slightly more than just a visualization of the number line. To me it’s a way of understanding the difference between the number of intervals and the number of division points needed to demarcate those intervals. In other words, the difference in the cardinalities of {(0,1),(1,2),…,(r-1,r)} and {0,1,2,…,r}.

Comment: Of course the difference **is** the number of intervals--I'm a bit slow--and a few moments of thought tells you why you want $n$ minus the number of intervals. I guess I only tend to use the fence post analogy when the intervals play a direct role in the problem. Maybe I should rethink that.

Answer (score 1):

I think of these problems in terms of slots. I want to form a product whose factors are the number of ways of filling each of the $r$ slots. When filling the $j^\text{th}$ slot, the number of items that can go in that slot is $n$ minus the number of items that are unavailable because they have already been placed in a slot. But this number of unavailable items is $j-1$ because prior to filling the $j^\text{th}$ slot $j-1$ items will have been placed.

So for the first slot, $n-0$ items are available. ($0$ items have previously been placed.)

For the second slot, $n-1$ items are available. ($1$ item has previously been placed.)

For the $j^\text{th}$ slot, $n-(j-1)$ items are available. ($j-1$ items have previously been placed.)

For the $r^\text{th}$ slot, $n-(r-1)$ items are available. ($r-1$ items have previously been placed.)

Here's another nice way of thinking about the final formula,
$$
P(n,r) = \frac{n!}{(n-r)!}.
$$
We want to fill only $r$ slots, but suppose we start out by adding $n-r$ additional slots so that we have a full complement of $n$ slots. These can, of course, be filled in $n!$ ways. Now we hide the $n-r$ added slots because we didn't want them anyway. Since there are $(n-r)!$ ways the hidden slots can be filled, our $n!$ configurations will include $(n-r)!$ copies of each visible configuration. So we need to divide $n!$ by $(n-r)!$ to obtain the number of distinct visible configurations.

Comment: thanks Will. Did you typo in your last paragraph? In the same sentence, you wrote "Since there are (n−r)! ways the hidden slots can be filled", but then "our n! configurations will include (n−r)! copies of each visible configuration". Don't you mean "(n−r)! copies of each ***IN***visible configuration"?

Comment: The way I wrote it was what I intended. For each way the visible part can be arranged there are $(n-r)!$ ways the hidden part can be arranged. All $(n-r)!$ of these arrangements look identical since the part in which they differ is hidden. So if $x$ is the number of ways the visible part can be arranged, then $x(n-r)!$ is the total number of arrangements, visible combined with invisible. But the total number of arrangements also equals $n!$. Hence $x=n!/(n-r)!$.